# Execute Command from Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I want to run a command inside of a script tag within my index.html file using node webkit.  Is such a thing possible and how would the code look like if I wanted to execute the command 'pwd' for example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Does something like this not work?

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

// executes `pwd`
child = exec("pwd", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
  sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks worked as expected, would this work for executing an entire shell script as well?

Comment: It should.  As long as you have the path to the script.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried several commands. I'm always getting: `Error: spawn ENOENT`

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for node webkit states:

> **Complete support for Node.js APIs and all its third party modules.**

Which would indicate that you could use the node childprocess api:

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html